# Typescript async function return type void vs Promise<void>

Tags: typescript

Is there a difference between typescript void and Promise< void > types?

Asking because I got confused why this is a valid typescript?

```
const asyncFunc: () => void = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};
```

Shouldn't this be the only valid case?

```
const asyncFunc: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes there's a difference

> void is a little like the opposite of any: the absence of having any type at all. You may commonly see this as the return type of functions that do not return a value

I guess `Promise<void>` doesn't require explanation.

---

Now why the assignment in the question is allowed? Because target function (`() => void`) can be called in all (*almost) the same situations as the source function. Have a look at simplified example:

```
declare let voidFunc: () => void;
declare let promiseFunc: () => Promise<void>;

voidFunc = promiseFunc; // OK
promiseFunc = voidFunc; // Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'
```

Comment: imho this is a pitfall though, typescript doing this in strict mode is not what i'd expect it to do since it will happily leave you with unhandled promise rejections. imagine something like this:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAMgS2gLhgCkwShgXgD4YA3EZAExwG0BdAmOgbgFgAoduAVzGCmXAwoAJ2QBzMQFNhAMUi4YAb3YxV8JKigA6OCGEBRAIbAAFpgQFiCXDlZsAvu04boWgA5cIZwxACeveB4+ATAFZTY1IRNhEAB3GDBJeP1hGOFMACIwEFhQEAAbDNt2e1sgA
instead of cancelling code execution, this will silently fail (with probably an unhandled promise rejection warning).

Comment: @GernotRaudner Yeah, it can be a big problem. It's far more commonly a mistake in my experience. Those unfamiliar with the behavior might think that this would be sequential, but it's parallel with no error handling: `largeArray.forEach(async (num: number) => await reallyExpensiveCall(num));`. Same with `stream.on('event', async () =>`.
See this eslint plugin: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md

Answer (score 9):

This will work as well (notice that this is not even an async function):

```js
const asyncFunc: () => void = () => {
  return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'hello' : 'world';
};

// OR this:
const asyncFunc2: () => void = () => {
  return { nice: 'very '};
};
```

why?? Basically, you can have typescript interpret the types itself, or you can set a specific type to a constant.

Here, you defined a constant called `asyncFunc`, which is of type `() => void`. This means that typescript will disregard the return value of the function when defining the type. Think of it as if the user don't expect a value, so returning a value should still work fine and not break the code.

### So, what's the type of `asyncFunc`??

If you define the type of the constant yourself, the type will be `() => void`, so the user won't expect any return value:
[image]

But if you let typescript interpret this itself, it should know the correct value.
So, for the function defined above (without the async), it will be `() => string`:

[image]

## So what should you do?

specifically for the case of defining a function as `() => void`, the function won't check the return value at all and you can return anything (even a promise).
**Defining a function as async will just wrap the return value in a promise**, which the `() => void` type will just ignore.

If you want to define a different type of the return value than the interpreted type, you can define an async function to return a specific promise with a nested type.

Something like this for your example:

```js
const asyncFunc: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};
```

The thing is, that this will happen automatically without the type definition:
[image]

So it's pretty redundant. you can just let typescript interpret the types unless you want to change the return type to something else.

So, in the example that might return `hello` or `world` we might want to let the user know that the return value can be **any string** instead of these two values.
Then, it makes sense to change the definition of the return value to something else:
[image]

You can combine any of these to achieve a workflow you like, but be aware that `() => void` is kind of a special case with this type system (since any other return value besides `void` will throw a type error.

Answer (score 8):

When you declare a variable with `() => void` type, you are basically saying that it could be any function. So its value (function) could return anything. Take a look at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2&ssl=22&ssc=27&pln=19&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAnmYAxArigXDAFAShgF4A+GANxAEsATY+JFPQ0mAbwFgAoGXmAJwCmUdPzAwwggO4wACvxABbKhEG4hEEABtyg4mQ3bdBfAG5uAX3NduoSLATI0mYACYcBfXIXLVAHkpaMiIGJ2YvTh4+OCk4KlhJGXklFTVDHT1WdON8M0trW3BoUJQMFABmekcmT1ZIvnhY+IlpbxTVdUFNDK9stVzrK25uauAYADMXKCpwEucUABYCHEC6euimhNbk3zSuo0yDfYyTQeGuUYmpmfFRsuAAVmW23YDqGjJ13hi4raSfVKdbq6XrHHJ5LgWIA). I put there a few more function implementations to you to see that declaring a variable that receives a function is different than declaring a function itself. 
Declaring the function itself has the behavior you expected.

```js
const asyncFunc: () => void = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};

const asyncFunc2: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};

const asyncFunc3 = async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
};

// TS compiler complains about it
async function asyncFunc4(): void {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
}

async function asyncFunc4(): Promise<void> {
    await new Promise(resolve => resolve());
}
```

**Edit:**
Found [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#callback-types) little explanation. It could help you understand it too. It says:

> Do use the return type void for callbacks whose value will be ignored.
>   Why: Using void is safer because it prevents you from accidentally using the return value of x in an unchecked way

Comment: ```( ) => void.```  "void" does not return any value...so how can it return anything?